# List into items nested JSON using getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a JSON Like below:

```
  {"sessions":[
    {
        "totalusers":"2",
        "Users": [
            { "id": 1, "name": "abc" },
            { "id": 2, "name": "def" }
        ]
    }
  ]}
```

I have my HTML as below

```
     <div>
        <p class="totalusers">Total Users</p>
        <p class="Users">Users</p>
     </div>
```

My Jquery

```
  $.getJSON("sample.json",  function(data) {
  $(".totalusers").append(data.sessions[0].totalusers); 
  $(".Users").append(data.sessions[0].Users.id[]);
 }  );
```

I would like all my users in the JSON to be shown in a list in the HTML. Please help. I am missing something in the jQuery "data.sessions[0].Users.id[]" to show the whole list.

Comment: Looking ahead a bit, will there be a `data.sessions[1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Praveen's answer is in the right direction but he is not using $.each correctly.  You will need to use $.each to iterate over each of the users.

```
$.getJSON("sample.json",  function(data) {
  $(".totalusers").append(data.sessions[0].totalusers); 
  $.each(data.sessions[0].Users, function(i, value){
    $(".Users").append(value.id);
  })
});
```

I would also recommend changing your HTML to use an actual list like

```
<div>
    <p class="totalusers">Total Users</p>
    <p class="Users">Users</p>
    <ul class="users-list"></ul>
 </div>
```

Then your JS would be:

```
$.getJSON("sample.json",  function(data) {
  $(".totalusers").append(data.sessions[0].totalusers); 
  $.each(data.sessions[0].Users, function(i, value){
    $(".users-list").append('<li>' + value.id + '</li>');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$.getJSON("sample.json",  function(data) {
  $(".totalusers").append(data.sessions[0].totalusers);
  var $Users = $(".Users");
  $.each(data.sessions[0].Users, function(i, value){
    $Users.append(value.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$.each(data.sessions[0].Users, ...`

Comment: You'd want to cache that selector oustide of the loop. No need to select it over and over. :) `var $list = $(".Users");`

Comment: Which selector are you talking about @MatthewBlancarte, coz I have used unique selectors.

Comment: @thomasfedb What's the reason of removing the semicolons `;`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar See my updated comment. You'll want to cache `$('.Users')`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Force of habit while tidying up.

Comment: @thomasfedb Wasn't this already tidy? I mean, there wasn't any indentation or spacing issues right? #JustSaying.

Comment: Okay, @MatthewBlancarte You mean to say that each time the loop runs, a new selector comes in place? Okay, I got it. Didn't think in that way.

Comment: @PraveenKumar exactly. This is fine for only a few iterations, but if there are thousands of users, jQuery will waste resources by finding the same element over and over.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewBlancarte Will take this point. Didn't know this. :)